# Can Bash register TSTP/CONT traps for its own "suspend" command?

Tags: bash, shell, signals

I suspect the answer is 'no', but I wanted to rule out the possibility that there *is* a way and I'm just missing some clever syntax.

The problem boils down to

```bash
outer$  bash
inner$  trap 'echo TSTP received' TSTP
inner$  trap 'echo CONT received' CONT
inner$  suspend

[1]+  Stopped                 bash
outer$  %1
bash

inner$  ah well shucks
bash: ah: command not found
```

I can already register a trap for `EXIT` in the inner shell with no difficulties.  Being able to run short commands when receiving the `TSTP` and `CONT` signals would be such an elegant solution to the new issues that have come up, but of course stop/resume handling in job control is significantly different than simply running a cleanup handler when exiting...

Can `trap` be made to work in this way?

Comment: `suspend` sends a `SIGSTOP`, which can't be caught; not a `SIGTSTP`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, *no*. `suspend` *apparently* uses an actual `SIGSTOP` (*not* `SIGTSTP`), which I believe (like `SIGKILL`) cannot be caught - someone please correct me if I'm wrong. Your trap for `SIGTSTP` is working fine, though. :)

Using your `outer$` and `inner$` "prompts" to indicate state and hopefully reduce confusion, though obviously nothing is setting them that way. My prompts were different enough to be clear, but too noisy to use here.

```
outer$ bash
inner$ trap 'echo TSTP received' TSTP # this catches - and effectively ignores - TSTP
inner$ kill -TSTP $$ # this raises a TSTP to the current process
TSTP received
inner$ suspend # this is apparently not sending a TSTP

[1]+  Stopped                 bash

outer$ fg 1 # this resumes the suspended job back into foreground
inner$ echo $$
1402
inner$ suspend

[1]+  Stopped                 bash

outer$ kill -CONT 1402 # this also wakes it up
inner$
```

Comment: You're right, it's using `SIGSTOP`.  It hadn't occurred to me that it _wouldn't_ be using `SIGTSTP`, although in retrospect that was a bad assumption on my part!  Clearly more caffeine is called for.  :-)